# What to use instead of 'context' to modifiy SVG?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I am trying to update an existing project that deals with **SVG**, written with jQuery 1 to run with the current version. It still uses the .context property which is deprecated and throws errors now of course.
I've tried anything but I've got no clue how to get to the object and change the text.

I found out that usually you could use 'document' instead of .context when working within an HTML document. But in this case I am trying to access a text label within an SVG element.
Using the old jQuery version I found out that the target object is the following type `[object SVGTextElement]`

```js
    labelMeasure = qSVG.create("none", "text", {
      x: 0,
      y: -10,
      'font-size': '1.2em',
      stroke: "#ffffff",
      "stroke-width": "0.4px",
      'text-anchor': 'middle',
      fill: "#3672d9"
    });

    binder.graph.append(labelMeasure);
    $('#boxbind').append(binder.graph);
  } else {
    cross.attr({
      "transform": "translate(" + (snap.x) + "," + (snap.y) + ")"
    });

    if (action == 1) {
      var startText = qSVG.middle(pox, poy, x, y);
      var angleText = qSVG.angle(pox, poy, x, y);
      var valueText = qSVG.measure({
        x: pox,
        y: poy
      }, {
        x: x,
        y: y
      });
      binder.size = valueText;
      binder.x = startText.x;
      binder.y = startText.y;
      binder.angle = angleText.deg;
      valueText = (valueText / meter).toFixed(2) + ' m';
      labelMeasure.context.textContent = valueText; // <--
      binder.update();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the error message when using the deprecated .context property:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object: (evaluating
>   'labelMeasure.context.textContent = valueText')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure, because I don't know what `qSVG()` actually does.

But you could try replacing

```
labelMeasure.context.textContent = valueText;
```

with

```
labelMeasure.text(valueText);
```

If that doesn't work, then you should update your question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

https://jsfiddle.net/wavmxpzq/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely right and does the job!